# Laravel: a simple route is redirected to /public folder

Tags: laravel, routes

I'm beginning Laravel 5.2 and I'm stuck with this simple route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function(){
  Route::get('/', function(){
    return view('admin/login');
  });
});
```

When I type `http://<my_site>/admin` I am redirected to `http://<my_site>/public/admin/?` instead of returning the view (I also tried with a simple `return 'ok'` and it keeps get redirected.

I can't understand where I am wrong, please a help?

EDIT: I found out that it's because I have an `admin` folder in my `public` one, that maybe causes conflict! But I'd like to keep the name `admin` to my assets folder, what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You should set up `public` directory as root direcotry in your web server configuration. For example, for Apache do this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myapp.localhost.com
  DocumentRoot "/home/vagrant/projects/myapp/public"
  <Directory "/home/vagrant/projects/myapp/public">
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The thing is if your web server is pointed to another directory (for example, the Laravel's root directory), your app will never work properly.